# How is this justified that I can delete a row and a column of a matrix if I set one value of the vector to zero?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have been reading Strang's Introduction to Linear Algebra. On page 428 (it deals with graphs, networks) I encountered something:

$$ A^TA=\begin{pmatrix}  3 & -1 & -1 & -1\\  -1 & 3 & -1 & -1\\  -1 &
-1 & 3 & -1\\  -1 & -1 & -1 & 3\\ \end{pmatrix} $$ The text says that this matrix isn't invertible so $A^T A\vec{x}$ is not solvable.

> One value of $\vec{x}$ has to be set to $0$. Then it says that setting
>   $x_4=0$ removes the fourth row and column, and this leaves a 3 by 3
>   invertible matrix. Now $A^TA\vec{x}=\vec{f}$ (with $\vec f $ being a
>   source $S$ into node $1$)can be solved:

$$ A^TA\vec x = \vec f==\begin{pmatrix}  3 & -1 & -1 \\  -1 & 3 & -1 \\  -1 & -1 & 3 \\ \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x_1\\x_2\\x_3 \end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix} S\\0\\0 \end{pmatrix}$$

**My question: How is this justified that I can delete a row and a column if I set one value of the vector to zero?**